# Criar componente via vue.js

Tags: php, html, vue.js

Existe algum componente via vue js que me faça criar esse componente que mostra na imagem abaixo eu estou de desenvolvendo meu site em PHP.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O [vue-slider-component](https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/example/) pode te ajudar. Parece bem versátil e com uma documentação simples.

Answer (score 0):

Já deve ter utilizado outro, mas apenas para ficar registrado para quem não conhece, eu recomendo a utilização do [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/). Possui uma documentação completa, está sempre atualizando, é simples e ótimo para trabalhar.

No caso do *"Arraste para ajustar"*, na documentação do [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start) há um componente chamado de [Slider](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/sliders) que resolveria.